# Please show effort and explain what you've tried when you're asking for our help

Tags: discussion

We are currently seeing a lot of beginner-level questions being asked on the site.

We don't mind answering these questions *as long as* they show that effort has been made prior to asking.

---

To our seasoned users:

When a user is asking for something to be done, but doesn't show that they've made any effort, please encourage an edit with what they've done. You also have the option to issue a vote to place the question on hold, pending improvement, if you think it is of a low enough quality to warrant immediate closure.

If you decide to post an answer to these questions, please do not do all of the work for the user or provide links to source files of the requested work. By fulfilling design requests you help to set an incorrect example of what our community is trying to achieve here.

We are not here to do people's work for them. We are here to assist them in figuring out how to do it themselves. In other words, to teach and learn from each other, but not to abuse each others kindness by asking too much.

---

If you think a question or answer is requesting or providing free services, please flag it for a moderator to review.

Comment: Well there goes my plan to upload my main hard drive as source files.

Comment: nice edit but Ill add more when I have time

Comment: related: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/can-we-have-a-canonical-one-beginner-design-question-to-link-to-them-all